# How to handle the discrepancy in precision between .NET CLR DateTime and datetime in SQL Server (and SQL CE)

Tags: .net, sql-server, datetime, types, normalization

In .NET the DateTime data type is precision to 100ns. In SQL Server and SQL CE the datetime type is not that precise .

I have tons of code that uses DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow. The values returned from those calls are then stored in the database. Depending on the value, when I pull that data out of the database, it will not match the entered value. As a result unit tests fail and business logic that relies on the comparisson fails

This has to be a very common problem. Do I have to go everywhere in my code where I see DateTime.UtcNow or DateTime.Now and round it down? If I do that, I would also have to prevent all future references to DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow. Is there a way to easily prevent that?

Are there other standard approaches?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of time resolution do you need in your application?

Comment: I assume you are not on SQL Server 2008 then? `select SYSDATETIME()` returns a `datetime2` value `2011-02-09 22:46:19.0848410` which is the same precision as .NET it seems?

Comment: The lowest common denominator would work (i believe that's SQL 2005, i'd need to see what that is). For the sake of discussion, let's say within half a second accurate

Comment: Can you please provide some code that shows us (a) how u create the date/time value. (b) how u save it (including the table schema). (c) how you reload it (so we can see if there was some implicit conversion happening).

Comment: I believe you mean precision, not accuracy. From my experience, user-mode Windows programs are never more accurate than ~12 ms.

Comment: You are right i mean precision. I'll edit the post